What is the stance of Judaism on discussing philosophies, beliefs, ideas, and practices of other religions or belief systems?
What are the rules or guidelines on how a Jew should engage with others who would like to discuss philosophies, beliefs, ideas, and practices of other religions or belief systems?

Are Jews allowed to discuss / engage in the ideas to some degree? Or is it shunned.
How does Judaism incorporate ideas outside the main canon / system? (Generally speaking)
Are certain topics to be never discussed?

This would help me ask better questions to the Judaism community in general, but also would serve as a gauge as to how to interact. Basically, what is acceptable conversation topics in the end.

Did God not bless Abraham so that through him all the nations would be blessed? How can those blessing be shared if you do not engage with others? :) That said, this forum in particular seems to want to shut down any inter-religious questions (unless the question is phrased in such a way as to put down that other religion - those questions seem to remain open....). So if you are looking to have honest discussions about other religions and with those of other religions, your best bet is another forum IMO. But this is still a great resources if you limit your questions to Judaism only.

The Torah is not just another book of philosophy, but "coz it's our one, we hate all the others". Look at how Rabbi Sacks explains the Torah. Maybe then you'll understand @RyanPierceWilliams https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aW_yeTNL1AI

@RabbiKaii It’s not that I don’t understand; many Christians are the same way. They limit themselves to only discussing and studying what they already agree with. They view other perspectives as a threat to their faith and - ultimately - to their salvation. I do not share their views, however. If you are secure in your faith, then there is no threat to you in having discussions with those of other persuasions. Rather: you grow as you refine your understanding and arguments, and you get to spread the Word of God to others - hopefully leading them to truth. God’s the God of all and not just Jews

@RabbiKaii I’m not sure which part of that offended you - not my intention. The above reflects my experiences both on and off this forum - with both Jews and Christians. Nor do we need to limit it to religion - just look at politics in the US (yikes!)

@RabbiKaii also, for the record, I haven’t said anything I’d be ashamed to say in person and in public. It’s a fact that most people - religious or otherwise - are group thinkers who only want to be around those who agree with them. In fact, I got kicked out of a D&D group this year - full of atheists - because in a Facebook discussion I debated a couple of them on the issue of abortion. I’m generally against it, with exceptions like the life of the mother being at stake. While heated, it was pretty civil. When we were done they brought my views back to the larger gaming group to kick me out

FWIW the Jews (orthodox and reform) I have had the privilege of talking to have been nothing but welcoming to talk about things. But maybe it was just the context, when I bring up things outside of their conversation trajectory, they have just quieted me down, and continued with where they were going with the conversation (it's me and a group, so not just 1<>1). So I am genuinely curious if it's okay to talk about things which might be considered taboo (like talking about witchcraft, for example). I am just a student of everything, so don't mind me and my wandering mind!

(I don't study witchcraft BTW though, it's just an example of a potentially taboo topic that sometimes I wonder about). Another taboo topic is comparing God to God in another religion like Hinduism (or even a philosophy like Buddhism), I haven't really had the privilege of going down these roads yet with Jewish folk. But I am also sheltered for sure, so maybe you are out there!

I also want to ask "why do you [Jew] believe in X", and really examine it from a secular perspective (or help guide me into the Jewish perspective). But I feel like it is somewhat confrontational at times (I try and word it as best as possible, so as not to be harsh or confrontational or judgy). And then I feel (self-consciously) that I shouldn't say certain things (but I don't know exactly what those are, hence this question).

Basically a great fear I have (and what is currently limiting me in going out in person to talk to Jews, Muslims, Christians, Hindu's, etc.), is that I am not allowed to talk about certain things, or that a certain topic will inherently offend someone, or that I will be quickly judged as stupid/incompetent/irrelevant or otherwise "bad" if I engage in certain topics. So I want to avoid that if possible. But if anything is fair game well then great!

The few times I have officially spoken to Jewish folks, like at an orthodox congregation or nearby events, are what I'm talking about mainly. I have many friends who are Jewish but most of them are not really practicing their faith on the outside to the degree an orthodox person would from my understanding (not doing anything but major holidays for example, or eating non-kosher stuff), and they have always been open to talking about anything without restriction.

@LancePollard my suggestion: find online theology forums that are intended for debate and in-depth discussion (not stack exchange). The forums will general post their rules for what topics are permitted in different areas of the site. While there are those who you’ll offend inadvertently (as seen above) for the most part - as long as you are civil then others will remain civil and they will be happy to answer your questions. One I used to use when I was in school was theologyonline.com. It’s gone down hill IMO, due to the loss of the myriad of members back when, but search around online

@RyanPierceWilliams gotchya, yeah I'm looking specifically to talk to Jewish people about their thoughts (or talk to Hindus about their thoughts, etc.), so don't want a general theology thing. But as long as I get the "okay" from a site like this, about Judaism specifically, then I will branch out to local congregations/events and start chit chatting away, well really, mostly asking questions and listening haha. Without fear of shame or judgement ideally.

@RyanPierceWilliams we could definitely use a cross-tradition StackExchange (Religious Studies stack exchange). Closest is Mythology SE or Philosophy SE (sometimes the History SE), but mythology is too far removed from Judaism, philosophy is too western-specific, and history is too narrow. Maybe one day we'll have a new SE :)

@LancePollard most theology forums  either belong to a specific tradition and/or else have sub-forums for specific traditions. Stack Exchange really isn’t intended for back-and-forth discussions like you sound like you are wanting. Albeit, the moderators of different stack exchange forums enforce the rules a bit differently for each forum. In the Christian Stack Exchange they can really crack down on these threads when the conversations extend beyond a few messages

You can check out the Judaism subreddit. That will present you the forum that @RyanPierceWilliams is advising you to seek out.

This shouldn't be closed as a duplicate. Discussion isn't the same as debate

Rambam writes as follows (H Avodat kochavim 2:2-3)

סְפָרִים רַבִּים חִבְּרוּ עוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים בַּעֲבוֹדָתָהּ הֵיאַךְ עִקַּר עֲבוֹדָתָהּ וּמַה מַּעֲשֶׂיהָ וּמִשְׁפָּטֶיהָ. צִוָּנוּ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא שֶׁלֹּא לִקְרוֹת בְּאוֹתָן הַסְּפָרִים כְּלָל וְלֹא נְהַרְהֵר בָּהּ וְלֹא בְּדָבָר מִדְּבָרֶיהָ. וַאֲפִלּוּ לְהִסְתַּכֵּל בִּדְמוּת הַצּוּרָה אָסוּר שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר אַל תִּפְנוּ אֶל הָאֱלִילִים. וּבָעִנְיָן הַזֶּה נֶאֱמַר (דברים י"ב:ל') וּפֶן תִּדְרֹשׁ לֵאלֹהֵיהֶם לֵאמֹר אֵיכָה יַעַבְדוּ, שֶׁלֹּא תִּשְׁאַל עַל דֶּרֶךְ עֲבוֹדָתָהּ הֵיאַךְ הִיא אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין אַתָּה עוֹבְדָהּ, שֶׁדָּבָר זֶה גּוֹרֵם לְהִפָּנוֹת אַחֲרֶיהָ וְלַעֲשׂוֹת כְּמָה שֶׁהֵן עוֹשִׂין שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר וְאֶעֱשֶׂה כֵּן גַּם אָנִי:
וְכׇל הַלָּאוִין הָאֵלּוּ בְּעִנְיָן אֶחָד הֵן וְהוּא שֶׁלֹּא יִפְנֶה אַחַר עֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים וְכׇל הַנִּפְנֶה אַחֲרֶיהָ בְּדֶרֶךְ שֶׁהוּא עוֹשֶׂה בּוֹ מַעֲשֶׂה הֲרֵי זֶה לוֹקֶה. וְלֹא עֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים בִּלְבַד הוּא שֶׁאָסוּר לְהִפָּנוֹת אַחֲרֶיהָ בְּמַחֲשָׁבָה אֶלָּא כׇּל מַחֲשָׁבָה שֶׁהוּא גּוֹרֵם לוֹ לָאָדָם לַעֲקֹר עִקָּר מֵעִקְּרֵי הַתּוֹרָה מֻזְהָרִין אָנוּ שֶׁלֹּא לְהַעֲלוֹתָהּ עַל לִבֵּנוּ וְלֹא נַסִּיחַ דַּעְתֵּנוּ לְכָךְ וְנַחְשֹׁב וְנִמָּשֵׁךְ אַחַר הִרְהוּרֵי הַלֵּב. מִפְּנֵי שֶׁדַּעְתּוֹ שֶׁל אָדָם קְצָרָה וְלֹא כׇּל הַדֵּעוֹת יְכוֹלִין לְהַשִּׂיג הָאֱמֶת עַל בֻּרְיוֹ. וְאִם יִמָּשֵׁךְ כׇּל אָדָם אַחַר מַחְשְׁבוֹת לִבּוֹ נִמְצָא מַחֲרִיב אֶת הָעוֹלָם לְפִי קֹצֶר דַּעְתּוֹ. כֵּיצַד. פְּעָמִים יָתוּר אַחַר עֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים וּפְעָמִים יַחְשֹׁב בְּיִחוּד הַבּוֹרֵא שֶׁמָּא הוּא שֶׁמָּא אֵינוֹ. מַה לְּמַעְלָה וּמַה לְּמַטָּה מַה לְּפָנִים וּמַה לְּאָחוֹר. וּפְעָמִים בַּנְּבוּאָה שֶׁמָּא הִיא אֱמֶת שֶׁמָּא הִיא אֵינָהּ. וּפְעָמִים בַּתּוֹרָה שֶׁמָּא הִיא מִן הַשָּׁמַיִם שֶׁמָּא אֵינָהּ. וְאֵינוֹ יוֹדֵעַ הַמִּדּוֹת שֶׁיָּדִין בָּהֶן עַד שֶׁיֵּדַע הָאֱמֶת עַל בֻּרְיוֹ וְנִמְצָא יוֹצֵא לִידֵי מִינוּת. וְעַל עִנְיָן זֶה הִזְהִירָה תּוֹרָה וְנֶאֱמַר בָּהּ (במדבר ט״ו:ל״ט) וְלֹא תָתֻרוּ אַחֲרֵי לְבַבְכֶם וְאַחֲרֵי עֵינֵיכֶם אֲשֶׁר אַתֶּם זֹנִים. כְּלוֹמַר לֹא יִמָּשֵׁךְ כׇּל אֶחָד מִכֶּם אַחַר דַּעְתּוֹ הַקְּצָרָה וִידַמֶּה שֶׁמַּחֲשַׁבְתּוֹ מַשֶּׂגֶת הָאֱמֶת. כָּךְ אָמְרוּ חֲכָמִים (בבלי ברכות י״ב:) אַחֲרֵי לְבַבְכֶם זוֹ מִינוּת וְאַחֲרֵי עֵינֵיכֶם זוֹ זְנוּת. וְלָאו זֶה אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא גּוֹרֵם לָאָדָם לְטָרְדוֹ מִן הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא אֵין בּוֹ מַלְקוֹת:
The worshipers of false gods have composed many texts concerning their service, [describing] what is the essence of their service, what practices are involved, and what are its statutes.⁠ The Holy One, blessed be He, has commanded us not to read those books at all,⁠ nor to think about them or any matters involved with them.⁠
It is even forbidden to look at the image of an idol,⁠ as [Leviticus 19:4] states: "Do not turn to the idols." In this regard, [Deuteronomy 12:30] states:⁠ "[Be careful]... lest you seek to find out about their gods, saying, 'How did they serve them.' This prohibits inquiring about the nature of their service even if you, yourself, do not serve them.⁠ This matter will ultimately cause you to turn to [the false god] and worship it as they do, as [the above verse continues]: "so that I will do the same."
All these prohibitions have one common thrust: that one should not pay attention to idol worship.⁠ Whoever performs a deed that reflects his concern with [idol worship] receives lashes [as punishment].⁠ The worship of false gods is not the only subject to which we are forbidden to pay attention;⁠ rather, we are warned not to consider any thought which will cause us to uproot one of the fundamentals of the Torah. We should not turn our minds to these matters, think about them, or be drawn after the thoughts of our hearts.⁠ In general, people have limited powers of understanding, and not all minds are capable of appreciating the truth in its fullness.⁠ [Accordingly,] were a person to follow the thoughts of his heart, it is possible that he would destroy the world because of his limited understanding.⁠
What is implied? There are times when a person will stray after star worship,⁠ and times when he will wonder about God's oneness: Perhaps He is one, perhaps He is not?⁠ [He might also wonder:] What exists above, [in the heavenly realms]? What exists below [them]? What was before time? What will be after time?⁠ Similarly, [one might wonder about] prophecy: Perhaps it is true, perhaps it is not?⁠ And [one may also wonder]⁠ about the Torah: Perhaps it emanates from God, perhaps it does not?⁠
Since he may not know the guidelines with which to evaluate [ideas that will lead him] to the truth in its fullness, he may come to heresy.⁠ The Torah has warned about this matter, saying [Numbers 15:39]: "Do not stray after your hearts and eyes, which have led you to immorality" - i.e., each one of you should not follow his limited powers of understanding and think that he has comprehended the truth.
Our Sages [interpreted this warning]: "After your hearts," this refers to heresy; "after your eyes," this refers to immorality. This prohibition - though [severe,] causing a person to be prevented [from attaining a portion] in the world to come - is not punishable by lashes.


Can you please summarize the key points? Basically don't question the Torah, don't worship idols?

Are you not allowed to do this, or is it just recommended not to do it so you don't fall into traps / heresy / immorality? How would a Jewish person (or a Rabbi) treat you if you asked about or talked about one of these things, out of curiosity, ignorance, and yet an open mind?

I will try to get to these next week, short and busy Friday! Shabbat shalom!

See also Tiferet Yisrael Sanhedrin 10 note 8 (the note by his son at the end discusses this Rambam)

Generally the study of other religions is discouraged and not something Jews should engage in. For example studying non Jewish philosophy was part of how Acher went off the correct path in Judaism. I'm not remembering the specific location but there is a gemera that says when he stood up in the study hall many books of apikorses he was studying would fall from his lap. On the other hand the mishnah in perke avos say know how to answer a non believer. This doesn't mean needs to know the other religion but how to answer questions based on knowing Torah itself.
